# python file reading mangling file's lines (Mac OS X) but not Linux

Tags: python, linux, macos, file-io, generator

I've inherited some code that reads enormous data files and packages up that data into chunks, sends it off to a server somewhere and carries on.

Sometimes the packager fails/dies/can't contact the server, etc, and the data file grows large. At this point, quite rarely, the little ArchLinux machine that performs all this fails to complete the process - at this point I grab the data and perform the same task locally on my Mac (for want of a better solution in the mean time).

The ArchLinux machine never has the same error that my Mac always seems to encounter, which is this:

The file is read `1000` lines at a time, and this is achieved using `islice`, which seems to be an accepted way of doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6335876/310391

The problem is that on the Mac, this ends up smashing a few of the lines together. The resulting list is `1000` long, but at least one of the lines will actually be a concatenation of a line, without the `\n`, and most of another line from a little way **up** (36 lines **back**, exactly 4096 bytes, in this example) the file (this makes some sense as the file is read backwards, see below).

Looking at the file's `seek()` and `tell()` positions before and after the `islice`, I get (e.g.) `3530855` and `3651687` respectively, a read size of `120832` bytes.

If I seek the file back to `3530855` when I encounter this error, in pdb, and then do `file.readlines(120832)` I get `1092` lines (`readlines`' size is only a hint, so that makes sense), and the munged line is not present (but the component parts of it are intact in their correct respective indexes).

There are no other processes reading from or writing to that file, so I cannot see how it would be 'shunted' forward while doing an `islice`, for example.

The position of the first `tell()` before the `islice`, given above as `3530855` is reached by a backwards-reader (generator) (the file is `os.dup()`'d, first, inside the generator), `yield`ing line by line - a loop on the generator `break`s when it has found a line that contains the last timestamp it successfully sent:

```
for line in BackwardsFileReader(fp):
    if somecondition:
        break
```

and

```
def BackwardsReader(seekfile, size=4096, pos=-1):
    """Read a file line by line, backwards"""
    fd = os.dup(seekfile.fileno())
    buf = ""
    whence = os.SEEK_END if pos < 0 else os.SEEK_SET

    with os.fdopen(fd) as readfile:
        readfile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        if readfile.tell() == 0:
            # File is empty, bail.
            return
        readfile.seek(pos, whence)
        buf = readfile.read(size)
        readfile.seek(pos, whence)
        newline_pos = buf.find("\n")
        if newline_pos != -1:
            trailing_newline = True
            buf = buf[:newline_pos]
        else:
            trailing_newline = False

        while 1:
            newline_pos = buf.rfind("\n")
            pos = readfile.tell()
            if newline_pos != -1:
                # Found a newline
                line = buf[newline_pos+1:]
                # Seek the original file to the end of buf
                seekfile.seek(pos + len(buf), os.SEEK_SET)
                buf = buf[:newline_pos]
                if pos or newline_pos or trailing_newline:
                    line += "\n"
                yield line
            elif pos:
                # Need to fill buffer
                toread = min(size, pos)
                readfile.seek(-toread, 1)
                buf = readfile.read(toread) + buf
                readfile.seek(-toread, 1)
                if pos == toread:
                    buf = "\n" + buf
            else:
                # Start-of-file
                seekfile.seek(0)
                return
```

If I don't bother islicing the file, and read the whole lot (on my Mac) the problem still happens, but not at that same place, and less frequently.

The only thing I can think of is that the generator might be progressing the file further backwards (by 4096 bytes, the buffer size) while islice is reading the file forwards... The weird thing is that this never happens on the Linux box. Low level file operations aren't my bread and butter, and when combined here with a generator, I think I must be missing something - can anyone suggest the next debug step here, or offer a hint about what might be causing this disparity?

Comment: I suggest to refactor the code into a generator that reads blocks from the file and another generator that extracts lines from a sequence of blocks. Then unit-test each in isolation.