# Generating the exact same random numbers in MatLab and JAVA?

Tags: java, matlab

I have the following MatLab code:

```
randn('seed', 1);
rand('seed', 1);
A = 0.1*randn(5, 10)
```

And I am trying to write JAVA code that produces **exactly** the same result.

Here is my JAVA code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.Math;

public class HelloWorld
{
    static double[][]  random_normal_matrix(Random r, int x, int y)
    {
        double tmp[][] = new double[x][y];

        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
                tmp[i][j] = 0.1*r.nextGaussian();

        return tmp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        r.setSeed(1);
        double tmp[][] = random_normal_matrix(r, 5, 10);

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                System.out.print(tmp[i][j]+" ");

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see if you run the code, here https://octave-online.net/ and here https://www.compilejava.net/ the results are very different. The issue is not just some difference in precision.

Can someone please explain how I can get the same results?

Comment: Are you trying to get two random number generators to give you the same behaviour?

Comment: "Random number generation is the generation of a sequence of numbers or symbols that cannot be reasonably predicted better than by a random chance, usually through a random-number generator (RNG)."

Comment: I am using the same seed value. Since the output is deterministic, it should be possible to get the same results with the same seed value.

Comment: It seems unlikely the MatLab and Java will use exactly the same method to generate random numbers

Comment: @patrick-hainge Okay, but the method matlab uses should be published somewhere. And I should be able to implement it in JAVA, correct?

Comment: may be this helps .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430471/java-vs-matlab-math-random-and-rand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the doc page of `rng`:

> ...
>
> `rng(seed, generator)` and `rng('shuffle', generator)` additionally
>   specify the type of the random number generator used by rand, randi,
>   and randn. The generator input is one of:
>
> 1. 'twister': Mersenne Twister
> 2. 'simdTwister': SIMD-oriented Fast Mersenne Twister
> 3. 'combRecursive': Combined Multiple Recursive
> 4. 'multFibonacci': Multiplicative Lagged Fibonacci
> 5. 'v5uniform': Legacy MATLAB® 5.0 uniform generator
> 6. 'v5normal': Legacy MATLAB 5.0 normal generator
> 7. 'v4': Legacy MATLAB 4.0 generator
>
> ...
>
> `rng('default')` puts the settings of the random number generator used
>   by `rand`, `randi`, and `randn` to their default values. This way, the same
>   random numbers are produced as if you restarted MATLAB. The default
>   settings are the Mersenne Twister with seed 0.

Thus, in MATLAB you can choose the algorithm that is used in the random number generation. You currently use Mersenne-Twister with seed 1, assuming you use a reasonably recent version of MATLAB.

CAUTION: Octave does not necessarily behave the same as MATLAB.

I do not know the Java side of things, so you should look up what algorithm is used in the package you are using.

Type `doc rng` at MATLAB command line to see the doc page I quoted from.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get same number from two random number generators defeats its purpose. It is extremely unlikely you'll get same results.

Comment: But I am using the same seed value. The same RNG with the same seed value should always produce the same results.