# Obfuscating names with human readable names

Tags: obfuscation, deobfuscation

I have to obfuscate human names with other unique human names

So say the twitter handle Jane Doe might be mapped to Sally Bates

This mapping must be unique: 1-to-1

I need to do this because of concerns regarding personally identifiable information.

Question:

1. Does anyone know of a software component(s) that does this?
2. Or is there a standing algorithm to do this?

Notes:

1. A permutation of the characters is probably not sufficient
2. The obfuscated name should be rememberable name like johnbrown, john smith are good nhoj is not ok
3. The obfuscated name should not be mappable by a someone who is not aware of the obfuscation strategy
4. The obfuscated name should be easily mappable back to the source name either by computation or by dictionary look up

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: oops sorry - my brain is a bit dead

Comment: Do you just want a permutation?

Comment: PS: you should be aware that removing the names alone might be insufficient to anonymize a dataset. You might want to take a look here: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_oak08netflix.pdf

Comment: @MichaelW - yes aware of that, thanks for the reference I'll read it. For now I'm focused on names.

Comment: I meant a permutation of names, not characters within a name. That would also be easy to look up for you afterwards.

Comment: @MichaelW, that will work - so I can devise an algorithm to devise this and I think implement it rather quickly but I didn't want to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: You could try [this][1]. Just make sure to store the original mapping.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124347/how-to-generate-permutations-of-array-in-python

Comment: I have exactly the same requirement. I want to display sender of an email but hide the actual name of the sender with another